# PostgreSQL boolean function for “does this database exist”?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a PostgreSQL function which takes a string/text and returns true if the database exists, and false otherwise?

PostgresSQL v12+, based on default postgresql versions in Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 & 22.04..

Comment: in psql you can use **\l**

Answer (score 3):

There is no builtin method, but you can run a SELECT query to get that. You need to connect to *some* database, e.g. `postgres`

```
select exists (select * from pg_database where datname = 'the_name');
```